# Locking error in sqlite using c#

Tags: c#

In my c# application i am inserting data into sqlite database as below

```
String sqlExpr = "INSERT INTO item (id, typeid, ownerid, created, modifiedby, modified,active,imageuploaded,logouploaded,language_item) VALUES (@Id,@type_TypeId ,@db_currentUser,@dates,@db_id ,@modified,@active_status,@image,@logo,@language)";

using (SQLiteCommand _insertItem = new SQLiteCommand())
{
    _insertItem.CommandText = sqlExpr;
    _insertItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Id);
    _insertItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type_TypeId", type.TypeId);
    _insertItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@db_currentUser", db.currentUser.id);
    _insertItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dates", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    _insertItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@db_id", db.currentUser.id);
    _insertItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@modified", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    _insertItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@active_status", active_status);
    _insertItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", "false");
    _insertItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@logo", "false");
    _insertItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@language", language);
    rowsAffected = db.ExecuteNonQuerySQL(_insertItem);
}
```

And ExecuteNonQuery function as below

```
public int ExecuteNonQuerySQL(SQLiteCommand cmd)
{
    int ireturn = 0;
    if (conn.DataSource!="local")
        conn = new SQLiteConnection("data source=" + DataFile);
    if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        Open(DataFile);

    using (SQLiteTransaction dbtrans = conn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        ireturn = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dbtrans.Commit();
    }
    Close();
    return ireturn;
}
```

where i am getting error as database locked, please see below error message,

> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: The database file is locked
>       database is locked
>          at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Step(SQLiteStatement stmt)
>          at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
>          at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)
>          at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>          at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>          at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteTransaction.Commit()
>          at ThingzDB.ThingzDatabase.ExecuteNonQuerySQL(SQLiteCommand cmd)

Is something blocking in using statement...The code resides in different classes.
please help
thanx in advance

Comment: why are you creating SQLiteCommand in a using statement?

Comment: @daryal, because it is a class implementing the `IDisposable` interface. It is considered good practice to dispose such resources properly as soon as possible by wrapping them in using statements.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov It implements IDisposable, but only implementing IDisposable is not an explanation by itself, you can use it inside using statements, or not; it only enables to use.

Comment: @daryal, yes, you are not required to do it. It's just that classes that implement this interface usually contain unmanaged resources. And if you don't call it your code will work but you might get memory leaks and unmanaged handlers. So, yeah, you'd better do it.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I do agree, just wondering whether it is on purpose to release an unmanaged resource or is there some other purpose than ensuring disposal.

Comment: SQLiteDataReader rdr = db.ExecuteSQL(@"SELECT max(id)+1            FROM   item");           
                int next_id = 0;
                try
                {
                    rdr.Read();
                    next_id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr[0]);
                    rdr.Close();
                    rdr.Dispose();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
                finally
                {
                    rdr.Close();
                    rdr.Dispose();
                }
                return next_id; This the query runs before insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a guess: from the last run of the program, which ended by termination, SQLite have left its lock file (or maybe you have another copy of the same program using this DB still hanging), and you naturally can't open the DB.
Try to manually delete the lock file which is besides the db file.

Comment: SQLiteDataReader rdr = db.ExecuteSQL(@"SELECT max(id)+1            FROM   item");           
                int next_id = 0;
                try
                {
                    rdr.Read();
                    next_id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr[0]);
                    rdr.Close();
                    rdr.Dispose();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
                finally
                {
                    rdr.Close();
                    rdr.Dispose();
                }
                return next_id; This the query runs before insert

Answer (score 0):

Use using statement or dispose and close sqlitecommand and sqliteconnection 
for example:

```
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();    
//Your query code execution
//Now close connection    
cmd.Dispose();    
_connection.Close();
```